# How to make a text dialogue appear in wxpython

Tags: python, interface, wxpython

I have been looking around the web since early morning and I can't seem to figure out how to get wxPython to show a dialogue box on my main frame.

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Window',size=(400,300))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        test = wx.TextEntryDialog(panel, 'Enter your word:',"New word","", 
                    style=wx.OK|wx.CANCEL|wx.CENTRE,pos=(100,200))



def main():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame=MainWindow(parent=None,id=1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

It just opens a window without a text dialogue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
Dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(panel, 'Enter your word:',"New word","", 
                style=wx.OK|wx.CANCEL|wx.CENTRE,pos=(100,200))

if Dlg.ShowModal() == wx.OK:
    test = Dlg.GetValue() 
del Dlg
```

As wx.TextEntryDialog is a dialogue class **not** one of the convenience dialogue functions ***you*** need to show it and get the value rather than just getting a reply.

Comment: So the second part somehow makes it appear just by verifying the modal? Also is there a way to make it appear on the main frame instead of opening a new frame?

Comment: For that you use a text _control_, `wx.TextCtrl`, rather than a text entry _dialogue_ the name gives it away a little.

Comment: Normally you do Dlg.Destroy(), not del Dlg.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm sorry if the question was annoyingly banal.